# Extra labels for heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, axis-labels

I want to display vector 'values' as a heatmap label. Does someone knows how to do it?
Here is my table1

```
#          drug-1   drug-2   drug-3 drug-4
# assay-1 7.045337 0.000000 0.000000      0
# assay-2 4.693248 4.430464 0.000000      0
# assay-3 4.505905 0.000000       NA      0
# assay-4 4.777868 4.765742       NA      0
# assay-5 5.549705 4.950920 4.546701      0

my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))(n = 299)
col_breaks = c(seq(-1,2,length=100), seq(2.1,4,length=100), seq(4.1,10,length=100))

heatmap.2(table1, main = "  heading",notecol="black",density.info="none", trace="none", margins =c(16,20),col=my_palette,breaks=col_breaks, dendrogram="row",Colv="NA")
```

this gives me

[image]

I want to have third lable

```
values <- c(3.1,4.2,5.0,6.4)
```

so my image should look like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in heatmap.2 the following argument

```
add.expr=text(x=seq_along(col_breaks), y=5, labels=values, pos=4)
```

I cannot reproduce your example so positions x and y might need adjustment.

Comment: I am getting error "object 'col.breaks' not found". I have used following libraries dplyr, dtplyr,tidyr,ggplot2,gplots,RColorBrewer

Comment: It was my spelling error, yeah it does display values byt I need some adjustment. I will work on that. Thanks

Comment: Glad I helped! Please accept this as your answer, thanks!